# Open a URL on program load and hidden

Tags: vb.net

Basically when the compiled program is opened, nothing will show up but "on program load" a URL have to be opened in a new tab in the browser (if it's already opened). If not, the URL will open in a new window in the default browser.

I did this work through a bat file and converted it into an exe file and it worked! but some antivirus detects that file as a virus including Windows Defender. So I don't find it useful.

I want this file to be clean.. I thought that coding a program with C# Vb.net C++ Etc.. should work and the antivirus won't detect it as a virus.

On Vb.net, I found this piece of code that will open a URL (but I'm not sure if it will open a new tab or new window):

```
Dim webAddress As String = "http://www.example.com/"
Process.Start(webAddress)
```

This is the code to make it run on program load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

This is the code to make it hidden:

```
me.visible = false
```

And finally the code to close the program after it finishes loading the program (opening the URL):

```
Close()
```

How do I combine all these codes so I just need the past it and compile because this is the first time I use VB.net

Comment: Create a console application and set it to run as a windows application in it's project settings. This will hide the console. After that just put that Process.Start inside of the Main() method and it should work as you need.

Comment: Jaxi, Thank you for your reply! I installed Visual Studio 2017 Community. and then when I tried to make a new project, I didn't find any option to select console application.. however I clicked on "Open Visual Studio Installer" and it shows me this: https://prnt.sc/iir4vj What option should I install? and is it necessary since "Universal Windows Platform Development" has a 13 GB of total install size. It will take a day to download 13 GB... is there any other way to just install what is needed to compile this simple program?

Comment: .NET desktop environment will be what you want

Comment: You can always install SharpDevelop instead, AFAIK that will do the same for what you need but it's a lot lighter

Comment: I have installed SharpDevelop and have done what you said, but when I run the program it shows these errors: https://prnt.sc/iisqz6 However, without changing the output type to windows application, the program does run and the console shows up then the URL opens.
What does the errors shown mean?
Another question, what .Net framework version in the project should I use in order for the program to work in any windows computer? The 2.0 perhaps?